# И снова запятые

Tags: пунктуация

Никак не разберусь с запятыми в выражении "серая или теневая зарплата", "серая зарплата или зарплата в конверте". Нужна ли запятая перед "или" в первом и во втором случае? Когда забиваешь в Яндексе, там без запятых, может, подразумевается или-или. Как же правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужны запятые.
Смотрим в [Розенталь, §97.2 Пояснительные члены предложения](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/46.htm#%D0%B7_02)

> Пояснительные члены предложения могут присоединяться союзом или (в значении «то есть»)

Это как раз такой случай.